React Native - Native Module - Double param not nullable (Bridge, Kotlin)
I’m trying to create a React Native Native Module using Kotlin. I want to use optional parameters, but the app crashes when I use Double?.
Example:
React Native:
const {add} = NativeModules.MyModule;
add();  // param not set

Kotlin with String? works
fun add(data: String?) {}

Kotlin with Double? crashes
fun add(data: Double?) {}

Crash:
com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeArgumentsParseException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference (constructing arguments for MyModule.add at argument index 0)

Although Kotlin supports nullable Double with ?, it seems like the React Native Bridge is incorrectly trying to use the doubleValue() function to convert it. This function doesn’t handle null values.
As a workaround, I could use a ReadableMap and put everything into it, which works fine. However, I’m confused about why optional String parameters are supported, but optional Double parameters are not. It makes me wonder if I’m doing something wrong.
EDIT: Tested with React Native 73.6 and 75.2 (latest)
EDIT2: I've looked into 3 popular packages. All use optional String params but never optional Double, Boolean and so on. It seems everybody is aware of it, but doesn't complain. As mentioned above, I'll stick with ReadableMap for everything now.

Which version of RN are you using?

React Native 0.73.6

Are you building a Turbo Native Module?

No I'm not using Turbo Native Module

It looks like it would be supported. Based on 73 docs even with old NativeModules. https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.73/native-modules-android#argument-types

React Native with older architecture with NativeModules 0.73 does allow type references with additional nullability added.
Meaning primitives like Double? (Instead of Double) do not convert over the bridge perfectly.

Since Double is already considered nullable, I think this syntax confuse the parser and then throws the error.

Reference here for NativeModules argument types are the types. Most of them are extremely strict and do not account for nullability well.
TurboModules with Fabric could possibly do this. Highly recommend upgrading to latest react-native at minimum 0.74 to benefit fully from them.
Examples with what I believe are just Turbo Native Modules.
This example is using using Double in kotlin syntax vs Double?

Turbo Native Modules using double

